# How to pass column value dynamically in an array and setting value by array index

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass column name dynamically in an array to replace the value if data does not exit belongs to particular index.

Here is my code:

```
var excelRows=[{"DWSDYear": 2019, "DWSDDepartment": "IT Department", "DWSDHeadCount": 12},
                  {"DWSDMonth": "March", "DWSDDepartment": "Sales Department", "DWSDSubDepartment": "Sales", "DWSDTTR": "50000"},
                  {"DWSDYear": "2021", "DWSDMonth": "April", "DWSDSubDepartment": "Telecom", "DWSDHeadCount": "14", "DWSDTTR": "60000"}];
    var ColumnArray=["DWSDYear","DWSDMonth","DWSDDepartment","DWSDSubDepartment","DWSDHeadCount","DWSDTTR"];
    CheckDataValue(ColumnArray,excelRows);
    //alert(ColumnArray);
    function CheckDataValue(ColumnArray,excelRows){
        for(var RowIndex=0;RowIndex<excelRows.length;RowIndex++)
        {
            for(var ColIndex=0;ColIndex<ColumnArray.length;ColIndex++)
            {
                if(!excelRows[RowIndex].hasOwnProperty(ColumnArray[ColIndex]))
                {
                    //Passing column name dynamically: Not working
                    //excelRows[RowIndex].ColumnArray[ColIndex]='<span style="color:red;">Can\'t be empty</span>';
                    //Passing column name manually: Working
                    excelRows[RowIndex].DWSDTTR='<span style="color:red;">Can\'t be empty</span>';
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

> Result Expectations: All null value(undefined) should be replaced with
>   fixed text('Can't be empty')

Comment: Another way of writing logic for solutions are also welcome.

Comment: anyone please ?

Comment: Resolved. Thanks to all whoever have tried but not answered. Here is the solution:excelRows[RowIndex][''+ColumnArray[ColIndex]+'']='<span style="color:red;">Can\'t be empty</span>';